# Open page sides and load content using jquery

Tags: jquery, load

Ok not sure what this effect is called, if somebody could share some insights as to what it may be called so I can search for it and see how I can do this.  I hate asking for code without having searched for it first, but without knowing what this may be called is what has me reallyyy stumped.  Here is the [page](http://www.flickmotion.net/) that has the effect.  If you can see that middle content if you click on it, it opens on the sides and load the content inside, I'm just looking for that effect, to open sides.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **[step-by-step tutorial](http://buildinternet.com/2009/07/animate-curtains-opening-with-jquery/)** from Build Internet on how to create a similar "curtain" effect using jQuery.

Comment: awesome thanks..why i didn't think of curtain..oh well thanks!